# angular $routeSegmentProvider traverse routes

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-routing

I use $routeSegmentProvider. I inject to my controller $routeSegment. $routeSegment tells me about the route which was parssed to build the current page (chain propertie). What I need in my service is a way to list all possible routes in my application. Is there any option to do it?

Answer (score 0):

You can access segments definition tree via `$routeSegmentProvider.segments`.